# PHP - CSV export - Add comma in column data

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I am exporting data to CSV and facing one problem.

```
$data['name'] = "Test";
$data['category'] = "category1, category2, caegory3";
```

When I export code to CSV, it exports records but make separate column for category1, separate column for category 2 and separate column for category3.

```
Current Output
-------------------------------------------
| Name | Category  |           |           |
-------------------------------------------- 
| TEst | category1 | category2 | category3 |
--------------------------------------------


 Expected Output

------------------------------------------------------------
| Name | Category                      |         |         |
-------------------------------------------- ---------------
| TEst | category1,category2,category3 |         |         |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

What should I do so comma-separated String fall in same column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have category values between `""` so the comma is not interpreted. You can change code like this:

```
$data['name'] = 'Test';
$data['category'] = '"category1, category2, caegory3"';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really take a look at `fputcsv`. It does exactly what you want, with different escaping characters and so on.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

If you wish to output it to the buffer instead of a file you can use `$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');` to write to the client.